# How to print a Kinect frame in OpenCV using OpenNI bindings

Tags: python, opencv, openni

I'm trying to use OpenCV to Process depth images from a kinect. Im using Python and   primesense's bindings (https://pypi.org/project/primesense/), but im having a lot of trouble just showing the images i get from openNI. Im usin

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from primesense import openni2

openni2.initialize("./Redist")     # can also accept the path of the OpenNI     redistribution

dev = openni2.Device.open_any()

depth_stream = dev.create_color_stream()
depth_stream.start()

while(True):

    frame = depth_stream.read_frame()
    print(type(frame)) #prints <class 'primesense.openni2.VideoFrame'>

    frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint8()
    print(frame_data) # prints <primesense.openni2.c_ubyte_Array_921600 object at 0x000002B3AF5F8848>

    image = np.array(frame_data, dtype=np.uint8) 


    print(type(image)) #prints <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    print(image) #prints [12 24  3 ...  1  3 12], i guess this is the array that makes the image


    cv2.imshow('image', image)

depth_stream.stop()
openni2.unload()
```

this is the output im getting, just a window with no image:

[image]

there is no documentation at all on how to use these bindings, so im kind on a blind spot here. i thought that the `frame.get_buffer_as_uint8()` was giving me the array ready to print, but it just returns `primesense.openni2.c_ubyte_Array_921600 object at 0x000002B3AF5F8848`.

Actually, i looked at the binding's code, and found this:

```
def get_buffer_as_uint8(self):
    return self.get_buffer_as(ctypes.c_uint8)
def get_buffer_as_uint16(self):
    return self.get_buffer_as(ctypes.c_uint16)
def get_buffer_as_triplet(self):
    return self.get_buffer_as(ctypes.c_uint8 * 3)
```

has anyone used this bindings? any idea of how to makes them work? thank you in advance

Comment: Docs say "Refer to the C API for documentation". PyQt5 does something like that too. Means that the signature of the bindings is identical to the c functions under the hood.

Comment: I checked the docs and didn't find much.. i'm sure i'm getting the right array from the `np.array(frame_data, dtype=np.uint8) `, the problem seems to be with the datatype of the array

Comment: (You may want to look at this : https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2 )

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Instead of using `image = np.array(frame_data, dtype=np.uint8)` for getting the image, you have to use `frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint16()`. also, i was failing to set the image shape correctly.

**FOR FUTURE REFERENCE**

To take an image from a depth camera (the Kinect is not the only one), using the OpenNI bindings for Python, and process that image with OpenCV, the following code will do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from primesense import openni2
from primesense import _openni2 as c_api

openni2.initialize("./Redist")     # can also accept the path of the OpenNI redistribution

dev = openni2.Device.open_any()

depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
depth_stream.start()

while(True):

    frame = depth_stream.read_frame()
    frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint16()

    img = np.frombuffer(frame_data, dtype=np.uint16)
    img.shape = (1, 480, 640)
    img = np.concatenate((img, img, img), axis=0)
    img = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 2)
    img = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 1)

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(34)


depth_stream.stop()
openni2.unload()
```

to use the color camera, you can use `dev.create_color_stream()` instead.